# Как проверить какой цвет на кнопках

Tags: java, android

На активности есть кнопки Оранжевого цвета, мне нужно все кнопки оранжевого цвета заменить на белый. Потому-что у меня есть другие кнопки, и их трогать не надо.
Я никак не могу получить цвет кнопок,и сравнить их.

```
 android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" //Оранжевый цвет

public void Active(View view){
        for (View but : buttons) {
            but.setClickable(true);
                but.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Тут даже нет попытки получить цвет кнопки.

Comment: @Эникейщик НУ я  и не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Да просто "никак не могу" подразумевает "стараюсь стараюсь, но никак не получается".

Answer (score 0):

Вообще если делать именно так как вы предлагает - это не тривиальная задача. Но как вы смотрите на то, чтобы всем кнопкам присвоить "selector" и у этого селектора сделать 3 state. Допустим state 1 - дефолтный, state 2 - белый, state 3 - ораньжевый. И просто получать state selector и в зависимости от него менять цвет.